# Is there a standard algorithm or library for representing data deltas?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a Python dictionary with fairly complex structure — multiple layers of nested values, some of which are dicts and some of which are lists. I want to represent changes to the data in a compact way that can be applied easily.

For dictionary-only values, it seems not too hard — you can just make a dict that mirrors the structure of the main data but including only the modified keys on their parents, and call a slightly modified .update() that detects a tombstone value in case you need to delete a key entirely.

But with lists involved, it seems to get a lot trickier. It seems like I'd need to come up with some kind of custom addressing scheme that needs to account for a lot of cases — you can't just naively use list indices as keys, because you need to support e.g. the removal of element 5 at the same time as an insertion between elements 2 and 3.

Additionally, if lists aren't restricted to being leaves, it's tricky to specify changes to items contained in a list while also modifying the elements of that list.

Is there a Python library that standardizes something like this? Or a standard algorithm/approach that's relatively sane to implement?

for reference, here is a function that implements what I'm looking for for dict-only data:

```py
def update(d, u):
    for k, v in u.items():
        if v == 'del':
            del d[k]
        elif isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping):
            d[k] = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d

>>> d = {1: 2, 3: {4: 5, 6: 7}}
>>> delta = {3: {4: 'del', 6: 8}, 9: 10}
>>> update(d, delta)
{1: 2, 3: {6: 8}, 9: 10}
```

Comment: I don't think insertion is an issue with list indices. Do all the list manipulation using the old indices. Only after all the manipulations are done, are the indices changed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If I try to do an insertion at an old index after an earlier item has been deleted, I'll do the insert in the wrong place.

Comment: I meant from the user's point of view, the indices make sense. Of course from the implementation's point of view, you have to be super careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user's point of view, I don't think list indices are as much of an issue as you say it is. The indices will only have changed after all the manipulations are done. Use the old indices during the list's manipulation.

From the implementation's point of view, we'll have to be super careful when manipulating the list indices. What we can do is maintain an "index delta `i`" though the iteration, and instead of modifying `l[k]`, we modify `l[k+i]`.

Here I'll use a dictionary for the delta, with list indices as the key, and these three possible values:

- `'del'` to remove the item at this index;
- `('insert', v)` to insert value v just before this index; and
- `v` to modify the value to `v` at this index.

Note that `'del'` and `v` are mutually exclusive, but `'insert'` can be cumulative: it's possible to insert more than one element at the same index, and it's possible to insert elements just before an index **and** delete or modify the element at that index. Se we want our dict delta to be able to map a key to more than one updates; i.e., to map a key to a list.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def update(d, u):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return update_dict(d, u)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return update_list(d, u)

def update_dict(d, u):
    for k, v in u.items():
        if v == 'del':
            del d[k]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d

def update_list(d, u):
    i = 0
    for k, v in sorted(u.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for x in v:
                i = update_list_once(d, i, k, x)
        else:
            i = update_list_once(d, i, k, v)
    return d

def update_list_once(d, i, k, v):
    if v == 'del':
        del d[k+i]
        i -= 1
    elif isinstance(v, tuple) and len(v) == 2 and v[0] == 'insert':
        d.insert(k+i, v[1])
        i += 1
    else:
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k + i] = update(d[k+i], v)
        else:
            d[k+i] = v
    return i
```

Testing:

```py
d = {1: 2, 3: {4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6: 7}}
delta = {3: {4: {0: 'fizzbuzz', 3: 'fizz', 4: [('insert', 3.5), 4.001], 5: 'buzz'}, 6: 8}, 9: 10}
d = update(d, delta)
print(d)
# {1: 2, 3: {4: ['fizzbuzz', 1, 2, 'fizz', 3.5, 4.001, 'buzz'], 6: 8}, 9: 10}
```

Comment: This is a really solid start, and at first I thought you nailed it, but my fears were somewhat justified: because you're using the old list indices, there's no way to modify the element at position n and also insert an element before it. when you do an insert, the element at that position becomes invisible, because you can't use that key again. (e.g., trying to produce the list ['fizzbuzz', 1, 2, 'fizz', 3.5, 7, 'buzz'], there's nothing you can put in the delta to specify that 7.)

Comment: @Personman What we need is a "multidict". I.e., a dict that can have more than one value per key. We'd want something like `{4: [('insert', 3.5), 7]}`

Comment: Yeah, I guess that also solves the problem of not being able to do multiple inserts at a location. I'll probably end up with something like this, but I was kinda hoping there was either a simpler way, or a nice existing tool to do it for me :p

Comment: This would have been a nice use-case for [more_itertools.always_iterable](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable)

Comment: @Personman Note that most functions in the python library follow this convention: Either the function modifies its input in-place and returns `None`, or it doesn't modify its input and returns something. For instance, `list.sort` modifies its input and returns `None`, and `sorted` does not modify its input but returns a new list. Function `update` above is a bit of a mix of the two, which is not very good style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the dict class that allows for addressing values by multiple keys:

```
class MultiKeyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, __k, __v):
        super().__setitem__(__k, __v)
        if isinstance(__k, (tuple, list)):
            if not hasattr(self, "extmap"): # This could be done in the __init__ function but I did it here instead to avoid overriding it for simplicity
                self.extmap = {}
            self.extmap.update(dict.fromkeys(__k, __k))

    def __getitem__(self, __k):
        if __k in self.keys():
            return super().__getitem__(__k)
        elif hasattr(self, "extmap"):
            if __k in self.extmap.keys():
                return super().__getitem__(self.extmap.get(__k))
        return super().__getitem__(__k) # Call the super function again to trigger the correct exception
```

It only stores the actual value once, either under a normal str key if that's what's provided or under a tuple key if the provided key is a tuple or a list. Additional keys are just saved in another dict for redirection to the key that the value itself is saved under.

This is technically a response to @Stef's answer but I am not yet able to post replies as I just created my Stack Overflow account and there's a minimum requirement of 50 reputation points.